# What is happening on the screen as you reduce the slit width? How can you demonstrate that mathematically?

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction, intensity

I think in the case of a single slit, as you reduce the slit width the central peak decreases. The width decreases the amount of light entering the slit actually decreases,so when the area under the central maximum increases.

But can someone explain to me how to show that mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can demonstrate mathematically how the intensity profile depends
on the slit width $a$ by deriving [Fraunhofer's formula for single-slit
diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction#Single-slit_diffraction_of_Electric_Field_using_Huygen's_Principle).

Let $E_0$ be the amplitude of the incoming plane light wave.
Then the outgoing light amplitude $E(\theta)$ into direction $\theta$
can be calculated straight-forwardly by summing the contributions
of all parts across the slit ($x$ from $−\frac{a}{2}$ to $+\frac{a}{2}$).

[image: single-slit geometry]

The path difference of each contributing ray (compared to the path length
of the ray originating from the center of the slit) is $x\sin\theta$.
And hence its phase is $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x\sin\theta$.
Summing these contributions you get
$$E(\theta)=E_0\int_{-a/2}^{+a/2}e^{i\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x\sin\theta}dx$$

I skip the evaluation of this integral and just give the result
$$E(\theta)=E_0 a \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\pi a}{\lambda}\sin\theta\right)$$
where $\operatorname{sinc}(u):=\frac{\sin u}{u}$ is the so-called 
unnormalized [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

From the amplitude $E$ we get the intensity $I=E^2$
$$I(\theta)=I_0 a^2 \operatorname{sinc}^2\left(\frac{\pi a}{\lambda}\sin\theta\right)$$

A plot of this intensity profile looks like this
(using $\operatorname{sinc}(0)=1$):

[image: single-slit intensity profile]

The central peak has

- a height of $I_0 a^2$,
- a width of $\frac{2\lambda}{a}.$

Hence the area below the central peak is proportional
to $I_0 a^2 \cdot \frac{2\lambda}{a}$,
i.e. it is proportional to $a$,
as you might have guessed intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [lecture by Walter Lewin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKO8n_-xtDc), which gives some context and a mathematical explanation as to why the wave of light through an increasingly thinner slit seems to spread out more.

If his explanations in that video are not clear, try watching the preceding videos.

Answer (score 0):

A narrower slit transmits less light, regardless of diffraction. It also transmits less water, air or anything.